# Scrollview inside tablelayout?

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout

I would like to set a scrollview in this table . How can i do it please?

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/lunchtableviewing"
    android:layout_width="194dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="4"
    android:layout_row="7" >
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, TableLayout inside ScrollView possible as:

```
<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/lunchtableviewing"
    android:layout_width="194dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="4"
    android:layout_row="7" >
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/lunchtableviewing"
android:layout_width="194dp"
android:layout_column="0"
android:layout_columnSpan="4"
android:layout_row="7" >
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```